# Get TypeError('Index must be DatetimeIndex') when trying to filter data on time

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the structure of the csv data:

```
Date_Time         Open     High     Low      Close     Volume        
2015-05-21 15:30  2128.00  2132.00  2127.25  2128.50  160643
2015-05-21 14:30  2129.25  2130.25  2126.25  2128.25   68195
2015-05-21 13:30  2128.50  2129.50  2125.75  2129.00   59661
2015-05-21 12:30  2129.75  2130.75  2128.00  2128.25   40547
2015-05-21 11:30  2130.00  2130.50  2127.75  2129.50   73274
```

I want to slice this data frame and filter on time and show all days between 09:30 and 10:30 (one hour).

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

ESData=pd.read_csv('ES-60min-Data.csv', index_col="Date_Time",sep=";")
print ESData.head()

df_initial_balance = ESData.between_time(start_time="09:30",end_time="10:30")
print df_initial_balance.head()
```

I tried this:

```
    df_initial_balance = ESData.between_time(start_time="09:30",end_time="10:30")
```

but get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
                     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
      File "C:/Users/tmgike/Dropbox/anders/Trading/Python/Pandas/range_analysis_ES.py", line 8, in

```
Date_Time                                                   
    df_initial_balance = ESData.between_time(start_time="09:30",end_time="10:30")
2015-05-21 15:30  2128.00  2132.00  2127.25  2128.50  160643
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2992, in between_time
2015-05-21 14:30  2129.25  2130.25  2126.25  2128.25   68195
2015-05-21 13:30  2128.50  2129.50  2125.75  2129.00   59661
2015-05-21 12:30  2129.75  2130.75  2128.00  2128.25   40547
2015-05-21 11:30  2130.00  2130.50  2127.75  2129.50   73274
    raise TypeError('Index must be DatetimeIndex')
TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex
```

I looked for the DatetimeIndex here on Stackoverflow, but could not find a similar issue trying to filter on time on a Datetime column.

Comment: can you try `ESData=pd.read_csv('ES-60min-Data.csv', index_col="Date_Time",sep=";", parse_dates=[0])`

Comment: Here is the csv file https://www.dropbox.com/s/1u0nc7iffkwpyc9/ES-60min-Data.csv?dl=0

Comment: You've not indicated whether my answer or my comment works for you, the point being that although you've passed the param to use that column as the index, it needs to parse it to make the dtype datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `parse_dates=[0]`:

```
In [170]:
t="""Date_Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume        
2015-05-21 15:30,2128.00,2132.00,2127.25,2128.50,160643
2015-05-21 14:30,2129.25,2130.25,2126.25,2128.25,68195
2015-05-21 13:30,2128.50,2129.50,2125.75,2129.00,59661
2015-05-21 12:30,2129.75,2130.75,2128.00,2128.25,40547
2015-05-21 11:30,2130.00,2130.50,2127.75,2129.50,73274"""
​
ESData=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col="Date_Time", parse_dates=[0])
df_initial_balance = ESData.between_time(start_time="12:30",end_time="14:30")
df_initial_balance

Out[170]:
                        Open     High      Low    Close  Volume        
Date_Time                                                              
2015-05-21 14:30:00  2129.25  2130.25  2126.25  2128.25           68195
2015-05-21 13:30:00  2128.50  2129.50  2125.75  2129.00           59661
2015-05-21 12:30:00  2129.75  2130.75  2128.00  2128.25           40547
```

Comment: Could you please explain what that command does? I'm referring to `parse_dates=[0]`.

Comment: @M-T-A here I'm telling `pandas` to parse the first column in the csv, `parse_dates` accepts a boolean, list of names or list of ordinal positions, and a dict, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)